# Convert Excel or CSV file into lists of email addresses in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, openpyxl

I have some experience with Python, but I'm not an expert so go easy on me here.

I have a Python script that sends out automated email reports to people throughout the day. Right now the email addresses are all stored in the script itself, but I want to have the email addresses stored in an external file where someone else can edit who receives them without having to open up the script itself. There are different lists of emails in the script, and I am struggling to figure out how to convert that to a file.

So for instances, these might be three email lists as they would be stored in Python:

```
Group_A = ['ABC@yahoo.com', 'def@gmail.com']

Group_B = ['xyz@yahoo.com', tuv@gmail.com']

Group_C = ['hij@yahoo.com', klm@gmail.com']
```

How do I store them in an external file and get Python to read them as separate lists?

I am fine using either Excel (either reading it through Openpyxl or Pandas) or CSV or even a txt document, but what is the best way to get Python to read the file and store the email addresses in their own lists? The name of the list also needs to be set in the file as each list gets a separate email depending on what the name of it is.

Comment: So, you basically want to transpose your csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your emails in a simple text files like this:

```
$ cat emails.txt
foo
bar
baz
```

You can read it into Python like this:

```
emails = []

with open("emails.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if len(line.strip()) > 0:
            emails.append(line.strip())

print(emails)
```

Results will look like this:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

> what is the best way to get Python to read the file and store the
>   email addresses in their own lists? The name of the list also needs to
>   be set in the file as each list gets a separate email depending on
>   what the name of it is.

I would just save each set of emails to a different file and read that file's contents to the lists you need.

the files:

```
$ cat group_a.txt
ABC@yahoo.com
def@gmail.com

$ cat group_b.txt
xyz@yahoo.com
tuv@gmail.com

$ cat group_c.txt
hij@yahoo.com
klm@gmail.com
```

read them into Python lists:

```
def readlines(file):
    lines = []
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            if len(line.strip()) > 0:
                lines.append(line.strip())
    return(lines)

Group_A = readlines("group_a.txt")
print(Group_A) # ['ABC@yahoo.com', 'def@gmail.com']

Group_B = readlines("group_b.txt")
print(Group_B) # ['xyz@yahoo.com', 'tuv@gmail.com']

Group_C = readlines("group_c.txt")
print(Group_C) # ['hij@yahoo.com', 'klm@gmail.com']
```

Comment: That's what I was getting at. I think I'll have to just save them as different files. Even though I didn't want to, it seems like the most logical solution. Thanks for your help.